# How to make Firefox accept insecure SSL certs and doesn't show message about "Potential Security Risk Ahead'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to access a page with Selenium that has a basic authentication prompt when accessed (a internal system) with a URL that uses HTTPS.

I wrote the following code...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

PATH_TO_FIREFOX_DRIVER = r'C:\Users\MyUser\PycharmProjects\some-project\drivers\geckodriver.exe'
MY_INTERNAL_HTTPS_PAGE_WITH_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION = 'https://example.com'

USERNAME = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'pass'

ff_profile = FirefoxProfile()

#trying to set Firefox to accept unsecure SSL Certs
ff_profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
ff_profile.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = False

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=PATH_TO_FIREFOX_DRIVER,
                       firefox_profile=ff_profile)

driver.get(MY_INTERNAL_HTTPS_PAGE_WITH_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION)

w_basicauth = driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(USERNAME + Keys().TAB + PASSWORD + Keys().ENTER)`
```

When I run, the script correctly fills the basic authentication prompt with username and password. But althought I have tried to set Firefox profile to accept untrusted SSL Certificates, Firefox still shows that message "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead".

How could I do to Firefox doesn't show that message? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit) and selenium 3.141.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It works (with Chrome):

```
import os
import unittest
import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


class testMyApp(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        chrome_driver_path = dir + "chromedriver"

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path,chrome_options=options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

[...]
```